# How do I print roman languages (e.g. Spanish) /special characters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

I've done some research and turns out that to encode special characters we use **encodeURI(component)** and **decodeURI**.

However when I try do something like:

```
var my_special_char = 'ñ';
my_div.innerHTML = decodeURI(encodeURI(my_special_char))
```

A "question mark" is printed.

I found this (non-complete) table about special characters: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/accentedcharacters.htm

Effectively when I do

```
decodeURI("%C3%B1"); // ñ
```

it prints **ñ**.

But if I try with:

```
decodeURI(encodeURI('ñ'))
```

I still get a "question mark".

How does character enconding work in JS? And where can I find a really comprehensive special characters' in **encodeURI** format (ready out-of-the-box to be decoded via **decodeURI**)?

**EDIT**:

- in my  (the application is an AngularJS application) I have **meta charset=utf-8** (written in the right HTML syntax as proposed in the answer, it actually comes from AngularJS' starter project)
- I'm using **WebStorm IDE**: I checked out the settings and the enconding used is **UTF-8**
- I'm serving the page locally in **Apache** (XAMPP)

**EDIT 2**:
as advised in the answers, I created a **.htaccess** file in **/htdocs** whose content is:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

as well as renaming both index.html and the view's file by adding **.utf8** before **.html** file extension.

then I restarted Apache (from XAMPP console).

But the issue is not gone. Any clue?

**EDIT 3**: I finally even tried to open the file in Sublime Text 3 and save as UTF-8 file, nothing changes

Comment: Are you doing this in a text editor? If so, check how your files are being encoded.

Comment: Is your JS code in a JS file or in the HTML file ? Are you serving it yourself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do any special encoding in your JS strings (apart for the special case of strings which may be seen as script element closing).

If your JS file encoding matches the HTTP header (most commonly UTF-8), it's decoded if you just do

```
var my_special_char = 'ñ';
my_div.innerHTML = my_special_char;
```

To help the browser, and assuming you're correctly serving the files with the relevant HTTP header (the way it's set up highly depends on your server), you should have this meta tag in you HTML header:

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
```

If your script is in a separate file, you should also declare the encoding in the script element:

```
<script charset="UTF-8" src="yourFile.js"></script>
```

Comment: effectively I use <meta charset="utf-8" /> in <head>.
However I still get a "?".
This may depend on the fact that the actual character is printed within an AngularJS expression

Comment: @dragonmnl Does the file look OK when looking at the source in the browser ?

Comment: Actually not. e.g. Fran�ais (instead of Français). The value is just fetched from an object, like: { id: 5, chosenLanguage: 'Français', languageId: 'fr', selected:false}

Comment: @dragonmnl Then you probably have a problem server side, meaning you're not serving the right http header. Or your file might be wrongly encoded. Check that in your text editor.

Comment: I'm just running Apache locally (XAMPP). Any idea?

Comment: First, check that your file is encoded in UTF-8 in your editor

Comment: @dragonmnl Look at this paragraph : http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html#fixcharset-server-htaccess (and at the whole page after;) )

Answer (score 2):

You should add `<meta charset="utf-8" />` inside your `head` tag. In this way the browser knows which charset to use and no more question marks will appear :)

Answer (score 0):

in classic notepad it solved by clicking

> file > Save As > in Encoding dropdown menu > UTF-8

in notepad++ by click

> Encoding > Encode in UTF-8

or by adding charset attribute into metatag `charset='utf-8'`

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
```